# Wie sagt man "to end up" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, verb-choice

> Mein Freund hat nach einem Autounfall im Krankenhaus gelandet.

My friend ended up in the hospital after a car wreck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Richtig:

> Mein Freund ist nach einem Autounfall im Krankenhaus gelandet.

Bei Verben der Bewegung bildet man die Perfekt-Zeiten mit "sein":

> ich **bin** gegangen/gelaufen/geschwommen/geflogen.

Letztendlich aber doch ein etwas schwieriges Gebiet - die Perfekt-Zeiten mit "sein".

"landen" für "to end up" ist gut!

Comment: Danke! Gibt es eine Alternative für "landen" in diesem Kontext?

Comment: Bei diesem Satz fällt mir nichts Besseres ein. Aber manchmal kann man to end up einfach mit "enden" übersetzen und kann das englische up mit "schließlich" oder "am Schluß/zuletzt" übersetzen.

Comment: man kann eigentlich auch: *Mein Freund lag nach einem Autounfall im Krankenhaus* sagen.

Comment: As rogermue suggested, other translations may apply in other contexts. E.g. "He ended up as a cynical old man" - loosely translated "Er entwickelte sich im Alter zu einem Zyniker"

Comment: Statt landen kann man auch "ist ins Krankenhaus gekommen" oder "gebracht worden" sagen.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen In diesem Fall könnte man sogar wörtlich übersetzen: _Er endete als zynischer alter Mann._